# Docker health check command. Do we really need || exit 1?

Tags: docker

There's already a similar question at [What happens to a Docker Container when HEALTHCHECK fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62212675/664577), but the secondary point about `|| exit 1` was not the main focus of the question (and it hasn't been answered directly).

The [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) contains the following example:

```
HEALTHCHECK
 --interval=5m --timeout=3s \
  CMD curl -f http://localhost/ || exit 1
```

I have seen several other examples of healthcheck instructions ending in `|| exit 1` around the Internet. Even when the only two possible exit codes of the original command are 0 and 1.

What's the point of `|| exit 1`?

Wont `curl -f` exit on its own with error code 22? Does Docker fail to recognise error codes other than 1?

Comment: No,  I don't think you don't need it. You could also try it out, which may be quicker than waiting for an answer.

Comment: I've tried it already and the containers does eventually become healthy. I'm just asking because it may be there to deal with some kind of corner case.

Comment: In the docs is written that possible value are only 0,1 and 2. So I guess it is more clean, https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Even when the only two possible exit codes of the original command are 0 and 1.

That's a big assumption that isn't being made by those writing the commands with `|| exit 1`. If a command exits with a 2 or any other code except for a 0 or 1, that's undefined behavior. Presumably docker is reserving other exit codes for any additional behavior they might come up with in the future.

Specifically with curl, it can [exit with a lot of other values](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/returns) which have a meaning for curl but would be undefined behavior for the healthcheck.

Comment: Fair enough, so when someone is sure that the original command only returns 0 or 1, then the `|| exit` part is redundant right?  I'm just double checking if there's no other possibility that would lead someone to use `|| exit 1` other than fear of unknown exit codes. I'm about to remove `|| exit 1` from a bunch of private docker / docker-compose.yml files (they are using handwritten healthcheck scripts that will only ever return 0 or 1).

Comment: You're shifting the responsibility to the shell script. If you own the script and can ensure that it will never have another return code (e.g. no one ever includes something like a `set -e` in the script), then yes, it's redundant.